# How to make wireguard ignore certain ports

Tags: wireguard

I have my router setup to port forward port 80 to a machine running a `caddy` file server.  I can successfully curl the file server from the LAN but I get a timeout when curling from the WAN.  The machine running `caddy` is also running `wireguard` through `NetworkManager` to connect to an external VPN.  If I turn off the `wireguard` connection I can curl the file server from the WAN.

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/702748/57570) says that my `AllowedIps=0.0.0.0,::0/0` is routing all traffic through the external VPN.  How can I set wireguard to route everything *but* ports 80 and 443 traffic through the VPN?

Comment: Could you be a little more specific about the `external VPN`? Does all of the traffic from the file server needs to go there?

Comment: @Mr.Diba.  The external VPN is a wireguard based VPN service like mulvad.  I'd like traffic in general to go through the VPN but not traffic to and from the caddy file-server.

Comment: I'm a bit curious as to why you would like to have all the server traffic go trough the VPN, does that mean that you would also like to have all the traffic of your network to go to the VPN provider?

Comment: @Mr.Diba It's not a proper server, just a computer on my home network that I connect to mulvad for privacy/security.  Problem is I can't do that and expose a file-server on that same computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to configure Wireguard to route everything but ports 80 and 443. This is because looking at the OSI network model ports are on a different layer than IP traffic.

But there are two (probably more) answers to this question: first answer is to limit the routes going trough the Wireguard tunnel. Evaluate which IP networks needs to go through the Wireguard tunnel and configure that in the `AllowedIps`.

The second answer is more advanced to do but you could configure a `source NAT` on the router which masks the incoming WAN IP address to the IP of the router. This means that the file server thinks that WAN traffic is traffic from the router and will send back a reply to the router which will send it back to the WAN.

Comment: The `source NAT` solution seems promising but I can't find that option on my home router.  It's likely that'll need to flash it with OpenWRT to try it. But I probably should rethink my architecture instead.

Answer (score 2):

Since Wireguard uses another routing table than the default one, you can use `ip rule` in order to exclude a certain type of traffic.
Wireguard will add a rule to match traffic after it is redirected to local, but before it goes to main.

You should then be able to add a rule before the wireguard one, which will redirect traffic **from** port 80and 443 (reply from your server) to the main table.
It should be as simple as:

```bash
ip rule add sport 80 table main
ip rule add sport 443 table main
```

You can verify the rule is placed before the wireguard one with:

```
ip rule
```

Although, if you want to make it persistent, you might want to add a PostUp action in your configuration file:

```
PostUp=ip rule add sport 80 table main && ip rule add sport 443 table main
PreDown=ip rule del sport 80 table main && ip rule del sport 443 table main
```

If you are only using NetworkManager, you can use dispatcher.d to place a script so it will be executed when a network is connected or disconnected.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo 'ip rule del sport 80 table custom
ip rule del sport 443 table custom
ip rule add sport 80 table custom
ip rule add sport 443 table custom' > /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/02-wg_exceptions.sh
chmod +x /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/02-wg_exceptions.sh
```